# How to encrypt environment variables in Rails <= 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

What is the best way to encrypt and use by decrypting `ENV` variables whenever needed.

Example `config/database.yml`

```
development: 
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DB'] %>
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

and `.env` has

```
DB_HOST=test.com
DB=testapp_db
DB_USERNAME=test_db_user
DB_PASSWORD=test_password_hard
```

My question is I want to encrypt `DB_PASSWORD=test_password_hard` to something like `DB_PASSWORD=xadbcxedaxdcda` and decrypt `ENV['DB_PASSWORD']` while using.

I know [Rails 5.2 onwards we can encrypt and use the credentials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_2_release_notes.html#credentials)

Is there a way to achieve this in older rails version <= 4?

Comment: You can use the following gem to achieve encrypted credentials with older rails apps.

https://github.com/ahoward/sekrets/